# Humble Video Seeking (Java Library)

Tags: java, video

I can't for the life of me figure out how to seek with [Humble Video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video).

My project is to play multiple videos, 100% synced, and I need to be able to seek to a specific frame.

My video will be an AVI, every video will be a very short clip (<30 seconds), every packet is a frame (I checked).

```
    //count the number of frames the first time
    while (demuxer.read(packet) >= 0) {
        numFrames++;
    }
    System.out.println(numFrames);
    //this resets me to packet 0, but so does every other thing I try
    demuxer.seek(videoStreamId, 0, 0, numFrames, VideoJNI.Demuxer_SEEK_BACKWARD_get());

   //this seek resets me to packet 0 also...
    demuxer.seek(videoStreamId, 0, frame, numFrames, VideoJNI.Demuxer_SEEK_BACKWARD_get());
```

I just need to be able to seek to the frame I want.
If I have to give it a timestamp instead of a frame I can do those calculations.

I have a 50fps video, the timebase is microseconds, so frame*50*1000000, but that doesn't work for me either...

I've tried changing the flags also but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was the problem. I was running this seek in a loop to thrash the code and try to work out any bugs I could. This will allow frame by frame seeking and backward seeking as well.

I tried adding flags together in all combinations I could, and finally found a note to some other flags that they should be or'ed (|) not added (+)...

```
demuxer.seek(videoStreamId, 0, frame, numFrames, VideoJNI.Demuxer_SEEK_BACKWARD_get()|VideoJNI.Demuxer_SEEK_FRAME_get());
```

I'm betting anyone seeking by timestamp would need the SeekFlag below instead of SEEK_FRAME.

```
VideoJNI.Demuxer_SEEK_ANY_get()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, or better share the context of the code, in order to be clearer? At the moment I am trying to seek back and forth, based on the input from a seek bar, but I can not make the seek work. I have looked over the ideas you suggested, but it does not seem to solve it. I was expecting that after calling seek method, I would be able to call again _read_ method, but _read_ will only return <0 values (which means no success).

Comment: A better way to put it, the question would be: how can I implement a video loop ? I believe that this will clarify all my questions.